# php-fpm как включить отображение используемой памяти?

Tags: php, логирование, access, php-fpm

Подскажите как можно включить отображение используемой памяти скриптами в access log, и где смотреть эти логи? Вроде как еще их можно в JSON формате настроить сохранение, как это можно настроить?

Comment: просто из любопытства, вы пробовали писать в браузере, php-fpm access.log?

Comment: пробовал, но точных инструкций не нашел...

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас уже нашел в конфиге пула /etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf это директивы access.log и access.format (и возможно slowlog). спасибо вопрос решен, все оказалось банально простым, просто не знал где конфиг у FPM теперь разобрался!

Важно прописать существующий путь для файла лога, иначе при рестарте FPM

```
slowlog = /var/log/$pool.log.slow
access.log = /var/log/$pool.access.log
```

можно словить ошибку
ERROR: failed to open access log (/usr/log/www.access.log): No such file or directory (2)